# Problema al insertar datos en una base de datos

Tags: java, android, sqlite

tengo unos datos que quiero insertar en mi BD, pero el problema es que no se insertan.

Creación tabla en BD:

```
    public class DB extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    String tabla ="CREATE TABLE Datos (Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, N text, P4 text, P5 text)";

    public DB(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(tabla);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int versionAnt, int versionNva) {
        //Se elimina la versión anterior de la tabla
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Datos");

        //Se crea la nueva versión de la tabla
        db.execSQL(tabla);
    }
}
```

En este código, `long i` es igual a -1:

```
EditText preg5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.precinco);
    EditText preg4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.precuatro);
    EditText nom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nombre);
    String nombre = nom.getText().toString();
    //String curso = cur.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String cinco = preg5.getText().toString();
    String cuatro = preg4.getText().toString();
    RadioGroup gruporadio = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.Grupo1);
    RadioGroup gruporadio2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.Grupo2);
    RadioGroup gruporadio3 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.Grupo3);
    //Spinner cur = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerp);
    DB baseHelper = new DB(this, "DEMODB", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = baseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    if(db != null){
        ContentValues registronuevo = new ContentValues();
        registronuevo.put("N", nombre);
        registronuevo.put("P4", cuatro);
        registronuevo.put("P5", cinco);
        long i = db.insert("Datos", null, registronuevo);
        if (gruporadio.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1 || gruporadio2.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1 || gruporadio3.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "¡No marcaste ninguna respuesta!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        else if (nombre.matches("") || cinco.matches("") || cuatro.matches("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "¡Dejaste campos vacíos!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        else if (i>0){
            Intent pas = new Intent(encuesta.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(pas);
            Toast.makeText(this, "¡Encuesta enviada!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ocurrió un error, intenta más tarde", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Que puedo hacer para lograr que los datos se inserten y que `long i` no sea igual a -1, sino que sea mayor a 0?

Gracias de antemano.

**EDITADO:**
Por si sirve de algo, esta es la activity donde deberían mostrarse los datos insertados:

```
public void cargar() {

    DB baseHelper = new DB(this, "DEMODB", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = baseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    if (db != null) {
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from Datos", null);
        int cantidad = c.getCount();
        int i = 0;
        String[] arreglo = new String[cantidad];
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                String linea = c.getInt(0)+" "+ c.getString(1)+" "+ c.getString(3)+" "+ c.getString(4);
                arreglo[i] = linea;
                i++;

            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arreglo);
        ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Marca algún error?

Comment: Si, el error es que se ejecuta el `else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Ocurrió un error, intenta más tarde", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }` Lo cual no deberia pasar, la idea es que se ejecute el `else if (i>0){
            Intent pas = new Intent(encuesta.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(pas);
            Toast.makeText(this, "¡Encuesta enviada!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }` ya que esto representa que `long i>0` y por tanto, que los datos se insertaron.

Comment: Intenta así: boolean i = db.insert("Datos", null, registronuevo) > 0; y en vez de pasa la condición en el if(i>0) solo pásale if(i). También que no se te olvide usar el db.close(); cuando ya no necesites la conexión.

Comment: Tampoco funciona :(. Creo que es el simple hecho de que los datos no se insertan.

Comment: Tú mismo has dicho que `i == -1`... por tanto, `i < 0`. Pero, por qué `i = -1`? En cualquier caso, si pretendes que ese código no dispare el "error", la condición debería ser `if (math.Abs(i)>0)`, pero, es eso lo que quieres realmente?

Comment: No se, simplemente i = -1 porque lo comprobe con una condición, pero lo que necesito es que sea mayor a 0.

Comment: si `i == -1`, seguramente ha habido un error al ejecutar el método `db.insert`. A menudo, las funciones que devuelven un valor numérico indican que algo ha salido mal devolviendo `-1`...

Comment: No puedes obligar a que i > 0, ya que aunque lo hicieras no te insertaría los datos. db.insert("Datos", null, registronuevo); te retorna -1 porque algo está fallando. intenta poner try catch o ver en el log a ver qué está pasando.

Comment: Ya lo solucione, simplemente tenia el codigo bien, y tenia que desinstalar el app y volverla a instalar

Comment: Y si los datos del registro están vacíos (o son incorrectos)? Vuando digo "vacíos" quiero decir `NULL`. Según la [ https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues) ](documentacion del método insert) si todos los datos del registro son NULL, deberías meter el nombre de una columna que pueda tener valor NULL, a través del parámetro opcional `nullColumnHack` para que no falle el método `insert`. <b>Pensar en estos detalles</b> es necesario para ver por qué el método `insert` está fallando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para validar la correcta inserción de tus datos puedes usar el mismo método [insert()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)), se realiza al obtener el estatus de la inserción, si es -1 indica que ocurrio un error y no se realizo la inserción correctamente.

```
   long i = db.insert("Datos", null, registronuevo);

   if(i == -1){
        Log.e(TAG, "Inserción de datos no se realizo.");
   }else{     
        Log.i(TAG, "Inserción de datos se realizo con exito.");
   }
```

---

Es importante comentar que al corregir tu script para crear las tablas de tu base de datos, si se creo anteriormente la estructura, puede no ser la estructura correcta y sea una de las razones por la cual no puedes insertar los datos. Si realizaste un cambio en la estructura de las tablas y no cambiaste la versión de la Base de datos, puedes optar por:

- Eliminar la aplicación y volver a instalarla para crear la estructura correcta.
- Eliminar el caché de la aplicación, al iniciar creará la estructura correcta.