# Almacenar un dato tipo bool en un entero para DB

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Necesito almacenar un dato de tipo bool en un entero, ya que había visto que las bases de datos android SQLite no permiten booleanos.
Pero no sé como, es para comprobar si un RadioButton está marcado, o vulgarmente "checkeado". Intenté esto:

```
int r1 = radio1.isChecked() == true;
```

Pero da error.
Y despues necesito un `if` para que si dicho RadioButton está "checkeado", que lo inserte en la tabla.

Asi lo hice:

```
ContentValues registronuevo = new ContentValues();
            registronuevo.put("N", nombre);
            registronuevo.put("C", curso);
            if(r1 == true){
                registronuevo.put("R1", r1);
            }
            registronuevo.put("P4", cuatro);
            registronuevo.put("P5", cinco);
```

Pero el if también da error.

**EDITADO:**

Código para cargar los resultados:

```
public void cargar() {

    DB baseHelper = new DB(this, "DEMODB", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = baseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    if (db != null) {
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from Datos", null);
        int cantidad = c.getCount();
        int i = 0;
        String[] arreglo = new String[cantidad];
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                String linea = c.getInt(0)+"Nombre: "+ c.getString(1)+", Curso:"+c.getString(2)+", 1. R/:"+(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("R1"))>0?true:false)+ ", 4. R/:"+c.getString(4)+", 5. R/: "+c.getString(5);
                arreglo[i] = linea;
                i++;

            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arreglo);
        ListView lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lista);
        lista.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Usa binario 1 , o 0 , int(1)

Comment: No entiendo, explicame un poco mas.

Comment: Me refiero que si la base de datos sqlite no te permite booleanos , uses un integer 0 = false y true = 1 , yo en las bases de datos siempre suelo guardar un integer de 1 , siendo 0 falso y 1 true.

Comment: Eso me daría error, porque cuando le doy un valor de tipo bool a un entero, no me dejará.

Comment: Me acabo de fijar , no pongas doble post .

http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54037/solucionado-problema-al-insertar-datos-en-una-base-de-datos

Comment: Es diferente, ese ya me lo solucionaron con strings y enteros, pero necesito ingresar un valor tipo bool, ya que es un radiobutton.isChecked();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola un gusto en saludarte, yo pienso que deberias hacer esto

`ContentValues registronuevo = new ContentValues();
            registronuevo.put("N", nombre);
            registronuevo.put("C", curso);
            if(r1 == true){
                registronuevo.put("R1", 1);
            }else{
                registronuevo.put("R1", 0);
            }
            registronuevo.put("P4", cuatro);
            registronuevo.put("P5", cinco);`

Y con eso puedes guardar el valor en la base de datos, cuando leas el registro lo que haces es algo como esto suponiendo claro que hiciste el query a tu base de datos y todo eso

`if(c.moveToFirst()){
      (c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("R1"))>0?true:false)
  }`

Comment: Gracias ese codigo me sirvio, pero el problema es que al cargar los resultados, no me carga el texto del radiobutton que es: `<RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="` **1/2 hora a 1 hora** `" />` sino me carga el valor `true`

Comment: me podrías mostrar el código que tienes para cargar los resultados? edita la pregunta y pones el código

Comment: Ok  ya lo edito.

Comment: por lo que veo en el codigo tu solo le pasas un arrelgo de String a el adapter del listview. y como tienes un radiobutton deberias tener una clase que tenga todas las propiedades que necesitas para llenar el listview. aqui te dejo un tutorial muy bueno que te puede orientar. Si de algo te sirvio mi respuesta marcala como correcta. Saludos aqui el link http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/10/android-listas-adaptadores/  A y te recomiendo tambien que despues de ver ese tutorial hagas el otro que es bueno http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/02/android-recyclerview-cardview/

Answer (score 0):

Hola edite tu código y puedes dejarlo de la siguiente forma :

```
ContentValues registronuevo = new ContentValues();
registronuevo.put("N", nombre);
registronuevo.put("C", curso);
registronuevo.put("R1",r1==true?1:0);
registronuevo.put("P4", cuatro);
registronuevo.put("P5", cinco);
```

Con esto , si radio uno esta seleccionado (true) el valor de 1 sera ingresado en registroNuevo , de caso contrario su valor sera representado por un 0(false).